# Can I automatically adjust screen resolution when remote-accessing Win7 PC?

Tags: remote-desktop, resolution

I often remote-access my work PC (big screen) from home using my notebook (small screen).  The difference in screen sizes means I have to reduce the work PC's resolution to be able to see anything clearly.

So, is there a way to detect when I'm remoting in and automatically adjust screen resolution?

Using Chrome Remote Desktop to remote-in, if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Google Foruns](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/9_kcPGAF1H8):

> We're working on a feature that will automatically resize the host
>   desktop to fit the dimensions of the client window; that should be
>   available soon.

Comment: That answer is over a year old, Google hasn't fixed this issue since.

Comment: Hi! Are there any new happenings to this feature?

Comment: still nothing google?

Answer (score 2):

Use Microsoft's built-in RDP Viewer to connect remotely to the system and have it automatically resize the desktop for you.

Comment: As a technician who's used a large number of remote control apps, RDP is by far a very non-performant.  With chrome remote desktop, I can control games at more-than playable speeds - and it can even handle 1080p video playback. As long as a directx compatible game is running in a window, chrome remote is able to capture it just fine.

I use a headless alienware small-formfactor to play games from my laptop. Sometimes I forget that I'm in a remote session.

Getting this type of performance in RDP requires running remoteFX on a server, and having compatible hardware.